# Linking QX11Info

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11

I'm porting an application qt3 -> qt5. As part of that I have in a .cpp file changed (Qt3)

```
mySystemstruct.display = theWidget->x11Display();
```

into (Qt5)

```
mySystemstruct.display = QX11Info::display();
```

Include has been added in the file.

```
#include <QX11Info>
```

I am not using Qt Creator. The file in question is not been linked using qmake. (other files has)

I get this link errors:

```
/home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/linuxobj//GO_C_QtGUI.o: In function `GO_C_QtGUI::initHistoryFilm(QWidget*, int, int)':    
/home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Modules/GUI/QtGUI/GO_C_QtGUI.cpp:668: undefined reference to `QX11Info::display()'
```

using this compile command:

```
clang++ -o gvs_GUI linuxobj/*.o linuxobj/libQtSpecific.a -DLINUX -I/include/ -g -I /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/include/ -Wno-deprecated -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -I/usr/include/postgresql/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui/ -fPIC -fPIE -I/home/go/ffmpeg_build/include/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/ -fPIC -fPIE -I/home/go/ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec -I/home/go/ffmpeg_build/include/libavformat/ -lpq -lippi -lipps -lippcore -lpthread -lgcrypt -lippvm -lippcv -lippcc -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/lib/intel64 -L/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/ -L/usr/X11R6/lib/ -lXv -lX11 -lXext -ltar -lavformat -lavcodec -lavfilter
```

Is it not possible to build using Qt libs not using qmake? My code has been built that way with earlier versions of Qt so it seems it should work.(?)

Since not using qmake for linking, I use `-I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras/ -L/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/` but it doesn't seem to work.

The QtX11-lib seems to be in place:

```
locate libQt5X11Extras.so
/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5X11Extras.so
/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5X11Extras.so.5
/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5X11Extras.so.5.2
/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5X11Extras.so.5.2.1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-L/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/` only tells the linker where to find the libraries.

You must then add `-lQt5X11Extras` to ask to link to the Qt5X11 library.